# I can't stop playing loop sfx in android cocos2dx

Tags: android, c++, ios, audio, cocos2d-x

cocos2dx 2.2.6  c++   android 5.0

it works well on ios. But when my game warning sound effect playing can't stop all the time.

exp:

code in button1: int sfxId = SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect(fileName,isLoop);

code in button2: SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->stopEffect(sfxId);

I can't stop the same sfx. But I fount that if I click button1 and button2 crazy sometimes. It will can stop the sfx. So I guess it is the engine fatal bug

Comment: care to show us the code you've tried?

Comment: I need some help me....~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I can't solve my problem. But I have a stupid method to do that. Yes, use schedule loop play the sfx. The bug is completely fixed.